# Estilizar overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho uma `ul` que possui "n" `li`s dispostas verticalmente.

Inicialmente, ela está com estilizar `overflow hidden`, apenas para uma parte dela, especificamente a partir da segunda `li` para simular uma `select option`.

No entanto, quando clico na primeira `li`, faço estilizar `overflow visible` e assim as outras `li`s aparecem.

Gostaria de fazer com que esse `overflow visible` não aparecesse de uma só vez.

Gostaria de aplicar tanto na abertura quando no fechamento (`visible, hidden`) um efeito de **abrir/fechar** como se fosse um **rolo**.

Será que é possível?

O código é do site [neste link](http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/index.php).

Comment: Com overflow não é possível, ou vai ficar aberto/visible, ou fechado/hidden. Você vai precisar trabalhar com o height.

Comment: pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Acho que entendi a pergunta. Tô elaborando uma resposta.

Comment: bacana. Estou na espera.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar um plugin pra jQuery pronto, segue um exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242696/3635?

Comment: Sim, de fato é sim. Só que estou com tempo agora e gostaria de ver na prática o que alguns css fazem. Estou dando uma estuda aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai conseguir o efeito que deseja usando `slideDown()` (veja as linhas comentadas que foram adicionadas no código JS que manipula a `<ul>`):

```
$(".selectOptions .selectOption").click('live', function(e) {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow", "visible");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").css("display","none").slideDown(400);
      } else {    
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").slideUp(400, function(){
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow", "hidden");
          });
      }

        e.stopPropagation();
      contador++;
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  /*Esconde o select*/
  $(".selectOptions select").css("display", "none");

  /*popula as li's*/
  $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
      $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });
    
  /*cria um contador para contar as aberturas e fechamentos da ul*/
  contador = 0;

  /*ao clicar na ul, abre/fecha a ul*/
  $(".selectOptions .selectOption").click('live', function(e) {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow", "visible");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").css("display","none").slideDown(400);
      } else {    
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").slideUp(400, function(){
     $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
      }

  e.stopPropagation();
      contador++;
  }); 

 $(document).on('click',function(e){
  if($(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow") == "visible"){
   $(".selectOptions .selectOption").trigger("click");
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
  
  /*ai clicar na li, busca correspondÃªcia na select option e o checa (marca)*/
   //$(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:eq(0))").on( 'click',function(evt){
   $( '.selectOptions .selectOption ul li' ).on( 'click', function( evt ){ 
       /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
    $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); 
     // Armazena nome do mÃªs que quer selecionar
  var li = $(this).attr("id");
  // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
  // options possÃ­veis
  var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
   // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
   return $(this).attr('value') === li;
  });
 
  // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
  opcao.attr('selected', true);     
     
   });

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.selectOptions {
 position: relative;
}
.selectOptions select {
 display: none;
}
.selectOptions .selectOption:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 top: 1px;
 right: 1px;
 width: 33px;
 height: 33px;
 background-image: url(http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption.setaBaixo:after {
 background-image: url(http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption.setaCima:after {
 background-image: url(http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/setaCima.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption, 
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
}
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul li {
 width: 100%;
 height: 31px;
 line-height: 31px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 2px;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
 border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 1px solid;
}
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul li:hover,
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul >:first-child {
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption  ul li:hover + .selectOption:after {
 color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="selectOptions">
      <select name="select" required>
        <option value="1">um</option>
        <option value="2">dois</option>
        <option value="3">Tres</option>
      </select>
      <div class="selectOption">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: O que é `click('live'`? até aonde sei em jQuery isso não existe, você deve estar falando do `live('click')` e acabou invertendo, de qualquer a função já foi descontinuada e trocada pelo delegate que fica embutindo dentro do `.on()` dentro de uso o contexto na ordem correta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente não conheço. Eu apenas deixei o código como estava e mexi apenas no que era relevante. Aliás, nem mexi em nada, apenas adicionei 2 linhas :)

Comment: Você pode até me achar um chato, excessivamente detalhista a um ponto de quase paranoia, mas eu sempre vou ser a favor de especular provaveis origens do problema ao invés de apenas tentar entregar uma possivel solução. Programação é assim, as vezes era pra funcionar, mas outro código ali meu conflitou e causou um problema inesperado que ninguém percebeu. Mas é isso ae opinião pessoal mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu entendo. Eu geralmente, quando vejo problemas absurdos no código que não tem a ver com o problema, eu melhoro e dou possíveis dicas. Neste caso aqui, eu nem tinha percebido esse "live", embora ele não cause nenhum efeito no código.

Comment: Mas deixa eu te perguntar 2 coisas: 1) tem como na hora de fechar aplicar o mesmo efeito? 2) E o lance de ao clicar fora (deixar a **ul**), como consigo fechar ela fechar?

Comment: então, é que, ao abrir, blz, o efeito está sendo aplicado. Mas na hora da ul se retrair (overflow:hidden), o efeito não está funcionando

Comment: só mais uma coisa: kkk, desculpe o incômodo. Mas do jeito que está, de fato, ao clicar fora da ul ela se retrai. Mas, se clicar de novo fora de documento ela abre de novo. Só falta isso

Comment: @CarlosRocha Fiddle atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/vjzogcw9/3/

Comment: Pronto, atualizado também, http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/

Comment: Agora, só para não deixar o outro colega no vácuo, amigo, eu vendo do php e sempre tive muiiiiiiita dificuldade com CSS. Então, como você pode ver no link que passei, estou aprendendo a fazer uns estilos da minha forma para aprender mesmo. Pois estou muito cru. Nesse caso, de nada adiantaria pegar coisa pronta. Está certo que adianta o trabalho. Mas no momento estou sem nada para fazer: me entende?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Eu tb não gosto. Evito ao máximo adicionar bibliotecas, só quando não há outro jeito mesmo.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Se quiser aumentar a velocidade do menu, basta trocar o 400 por algo menor, como 200... acho que fica melhor.

Comment: Acho que está legal.Está um pouco parecido com os outros efeitos que estou usando.Mas diz aê: ficou legal? Agora é dar uma estuda legal nas modificações para eu entender bem.

Comment: Outra situação ocorreu: está atualizado lá no site, é que fui colocar em vez de overflow: visibily, overflow:,scrool e alterei a altura para esconder parte das lis . Funcionou beleza. Porém, a seta para cima do scroll, ficou em baixo da seta que já tinha lá. Assim, ela não aparece. Algum recurso?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Adicione o código `$(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("width","200px");` quando fechar e `$(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("width","217px");` quando abrir.

Comment: Vou precisar fazer algumas contas, pois deste jeito temos 2 problemas, embora o visual ficou fera: 1) caso tenha até 3 opções, por exemplo, não pode ter scrool, precisa ser visibility. E se tiver de 4 para mais ai sim precisa ter scroll

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de tentar criar um select customizado do zero, porque não simplesmente usa um select de verdade e customiza ele usando algum plugin para jQuery (já que você está de fato usando jQuery), um exemplo de plugin muito bom é o http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/

Assim ao invés de ter toda a dificuldade de pegar o valor do seu select com ul e li usando `.text()` e talvez sendo obrigado a usar `$.trim`, você pode simplesmente usar `$("select").val();` e terá o valor

Veja um exemplo de uso:

```js
$('select.customizado').selectBox();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox/316c77f1/jquery.selectBox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox/316c77f1/jquery.selectBox.js"></script>

<select class="customizado combo-1">
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="baz">Baz</option>
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="baz">Baz</option>
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="baz">Baz</option>
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="baz">Baz</option>
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
<option value="bar">Bar</option>
<option value="baz">Baz</option>
</select>

<button onclick="console.log($('.combo-1').val());">Troque o valor e clique aqui</button>

<hr>

<select class="customizado combo-2">
<option value="foobar">Foo bar</option>
<option value="barbaz">Bar baz</option>
<option value="bazfoo">Baz foo</option>
<option value="foobar">Foo bar</option>
<option value="barbaz">Bar baz</option>
<option value="bazfoo">Baz foo</option>
<option value="foobar">Foo bar</option>
<option value="barbaz">Bar baz</option>
<option value="bazfoo">Baz foo</option>
<option value="foobar">Foo bar</option>
<option value="barbaz">Bar baz</option>
<option value="bazfoo">Baz foo</option>
</select>

<button onclick="console.log($('.combo-2').val());">Troque o valor e clique aqui</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

@dvdsamm, acho que consegui o efeito final.

Mas alguma coisa não está legal.
Quando fecha a **ul**, então está havendo um atraso em relação à contração da div pai da ul. 
Onde foi que errei?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  /*popula as li's*/
  $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
      $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

  /*cria um contador para contar as aberturas e fechamentos da ul*/
  contador = 0;

  /*ao clicar na ul, abre/fecha a ul*/
  $(".selectOptions .selectOption").click(function(e) {

      quantasLis = $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li" ).length; 

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {                 

          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").css("display","none").slideDown(400);

          if(quantasLis > 4) {        
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("width", "217px");
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css('height', '175px');
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll") ;
          } else {
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("width", "200px");
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css('height', 'auto');
          }

      } else {    

          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("width", "200px");
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:first)").slideUp(400, function(){
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
              $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css('height', '35px');
          });
      }

      e.stopPropagation();
      contador++;
  });   

  $(document).on('click',function(e){
      if($(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").css("overflow") == "visible"){
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").trigger("click");
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

/*ai clicar na li, busca correspondÃªcia na select option e o checa (marca)*/
 //$(".selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:eq(0))").on( 'click',function(evt){
 $( '.selectOptions .selectOption ul li' ).on( 'click', function( evt ){ 
     /*Joga a li selecionada ao topo da ul*/
     $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); 
      // Armazena nome do mÃªs que quer selecionar
      var li = $(this).attr("id");
      // Guarda em opcao o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
      // options possÃ­veis
      var opcao = $('.selectOptions select option').filter(function() {
          // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteÃºdo que o desejado
          return $(this).attr('value') === li;
      });

      // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
      opcao.attr('selected', true);        

 });

});
```